# Winter tires vs all season tires

Tags: tires, winter

I live in East Tennessee where the winters are generally quite short.  The roads can be very icy and snowy during the 2-3 months of winter-  but usually only for short periods.  I was told that if I buy snow tires, they will wear out quickly from driving mostly on the asphalt, and that they may even be worse than all- season tires on wet roads- which we do have a lot of.  It appears that most people living here don't have snow tires. 
I have an old  Mazda Protege which doesn't have much traction in snow or ice,  and which I don't believe has anti-lock brakes.  I now need to buy 4 new tires.  Should I go with snow tires, given the lack of consistent snow, or would all- season be enough.

Comment: You can find a lot of information in this question : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/49138/cheap-winter-tires-vs-high-quality-all-seasons

Answer (score 1):

If you have icy roads, get winter tires. They do not wear out more quickly from running on asphalt, they only wear out more quickly if the temperature is way too high for them (above 50 F).

One way to reduce this is to get them on as late into the season as possible and to get them off as early into the season as possible. Watch the weather. Have them put on when icy conditions are realistically going to happen "very soon", have them taken off when there will realistically not be any icy conditions anymore.

Do keep in mind tire shops often get busy at this time of year, so you may need to book in advance.

I have winter tires for all my vehicles, they make a huge difference. Whenever there's a blizzard or simply icy conditions, I'm in perfect control of my vehicle and everybody else is slipping and sliding. They're not a guarantee of traction though, just a huge advantage.