# Winter Tires - 2017 Audi A3

Tags: tires, audi, winter

I have a 2017 Audi A3 Sedan. The all-seasons on my car are 225/40R18. I’m looking at 16” inch tires and wheels due to huge cost difference. Can I get a set of 205/55R16 tires and wheels package? Will there by any issues?

Comment: What climate region do you live in? Since you mentioned your main set of tires are all-seasons, if you're concerned with saving money, you might be safe just using the all-seasons. Though, that may depend on the quality of the tires that you have as well (what tires are they?).

Comment: If you live in the EU: Is the desired size registered in your registration papers?

Comment: All season tires: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/49138/cheap-winter-tires-vs-high-quality-all-seasons

Answer (score 0):

Checking on Tire Rack, they recommend 225/50 16 as an optional size. I would tend to go with that width as it will feel closer in terms of handling to your stock tires. If you get new tires that are significantly skinnier (like 205), you will also be getting skinny wheels. You might not like how the wheels will look like they’re tucked under the car (unless you also get spacers).

In short, yes, you can get lower price options for tire and wheel combinations. I think you should stay as close to stock as possible, though.

Comment: You should consider two dimensions, the rolling radius and the offset...

Comment: For regular street driving, I'd argue that having the same tire width for "handling feel" is mostly irrelevant. Generally winter tires of the same size as all-seasons or summers will already feel somewhat mushier, and the extra sidewall from downsizing the rim will have an impact as well. I also think that if OP is willing to downsize from 18" to 16" for cost, his primary concern isn't going to be the aesthetic of tucked wheels.

Comment: You also want to consider the model of the vehicle.  If it's a 1.6 then I'm sure 16" wheels will be fine but if it's a fire-breathing turbocharged quattro you may find that 16" wheels don't fit over the front brakes.  Checking the diameter of the spare (if it has one) may give you a clue.

Comment: Also, regarding tyre width, in snow narrow tyres give you a traction advantage as they cut through the snow better.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see 205/55R16 is fine for the A3, rim size should be 6.5Jx16 with an offset of ET46. Diameter is pretty close between that and your stock wheels (0.2" smaller for the 16" wheels) and you're coming down in width by 0.8" which if anything will be of help in winter conditions.